# jQuery slideToggle() poor performance and/or freezes IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer-8, slidetoggle

I am experiencing very poor performance with the .slideToggle jQuery function in IE8. Its either choppy or it completely freezes the browser. Works great in firefox chrome opera etc.

I think it might be related to my DOCTYPE attribute? I am not sure. However, I have tried many solutions mentioned around the this site and others but none of them have worked so far, that includes making sure none of the sliding elements are set to position: relative.

Here is the script and html. Basically when the user clicks a button on a radio list contained in an upper div that upper div collapses and the lower div opens up with more buttons. They are hidden initially hence the check against .css('display'):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 function btnList_Type_Click() {

    $('#btnList_Type_Div').slideToggle(200, null);

    if ($("#btnPanelTwo").css('display') == 'none') {

        $('#btnPanelTwo').slideToggle(200, null);
    }

    if ($("#btnList_Date_Div").css('display') == 'none') {

        $('#btnList_Date_Div').slideToggle(200, null); 
    } 
}


     <div id="btnPanelTwo" class="lightPanel" onmouseover="page.cursor('pointer')" onmouseout="page.cursor('default')"  
     style="height: 36px; width:320px; margin-left:20px; margin-top:0px; display:none;">
    <span style="font-size: 13pt; left: 14px; top:10px;">Step 2: &nbsp&nbsp Choose Date Range:</span>
    </div>
    <div id="btnList_Date_Div" style="margin-left:60px; width:320px; height:325px; display:none;">
    <asp:RadioButtonList 
         ID="btnList_Date" runat="server" style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top:12px;" 
         Width="226px" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="11pt"              
     </asp:RadioButtonList>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_StartRange" class="textbox" runat="server" style="margin-left: 46px; margin-top:10px;" 
         Height="22px" Width="98px"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txt_EndRange" class="textbox" runat="server" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top:10px;"
         Height="22px" Width="98px"></asp:TextBox> <br />
       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_Submit" class="button" 
                        Style="float:right; margin-top:40px; margin-right:56px;" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_Submit_Click" />
                                 <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_StartRange" >
                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                 <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_EndRange" >
                                   </asp:CalendarExtender>
       </div>
       </div>
```

EDIT Here is the rendered HTML as requested:

```
<DIV style="WIDTH: 320px; HEIGHT: 36px; MARGIN-LEFT: 20px" id=btnPanel 
class=lightPanel onmouseover="page.cursor('pointer')" 
onmouseout="page.cursor('default')"><SPAN 
style="FONT-SIZE: 13pt; TOP: 10px; LEFT: 14px" id=btnPanel_Text>Step 1: 
&nbsp;&nbsp; Select a Type of Report:</SPAN> </DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 320px; MARGIN-LEFT: 60px" id=btnList_Type_Div>
<TABLE style="MARGIN-TOP: 12px; MARGIN-LEFT: 35px; FONT-SIZE: 11pt" 
id=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList_Type>
<TBODY>
<TR>
  <TD><INPUT id=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList_Type_0 
  onclick=btnList_Type_Click(); value=1 type=radio 
  name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnList_Type><LABEL 
  for=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList_Type_0>Label0</LABEL></TD></TR>
  <TR>
  <TD><INPUT id=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList_Type_1 
   onclick=btnList_Type_Click(); value=2 type=radio 
  name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnList_Type><LABEL 
   for=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList_Type_1>Label1</LABEL></TD></TR>
<TR>
 <TD><INPUT id=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList_Type_2 
  onclick=btnList_Type_Click(); value=3 type=radio 
  name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnList_Type><LABEL 
  for=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList_Type_2>Label2</LABEL></TD></TR>
<TR>
 <TD><INPUT id=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList_Type_3 
  onclick=btnList_Type_Click(); value=4 type=radio 
  name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnList_Type><LABEL 
  for=ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList_Type_3>Label3</LABEL></TD></TR>
```

Label4
    Step 2:    Choose Date 
    Range: 
    
    
     
      
       Label1
      
        Label2
      
        Label3
      
        Label4

Comment: Completely unrelated to the problem, but `.slideToggle`'s 2nd parameter is optional, no need to pass `null`, just `.slideToggle(200)`

Comment: Troubleshoot it with [Firebug Lite for Explorer](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

Comment: Not sure how to do that. I can run Firebug Lite but the console is empty, is it command-line driven? Can it debug a complete freeze of IE? Also I should add that this seems to work fine in my development environment inside visual studio. The bug appears once deployed on the server.

Comment: @Sparky625 no need to use any add-ons. IE 9 has a built-in developer window that allows you to debug things like Firebug and change the Document Mode to IE7-9.

Comment: Probably unrelated but why the javascript for the pointer in `btnPanelTwo`? Be rid of that, replace with css `cursor: pointer`. But remote possibility it is related, since that panel is one that is operated on, maybe the action is causing it to fire repeatedly.

Comment: Do you have a link to a working page? Hard to profile something that by the looks of it is missing whole bunch of code. Performance greatly depends on number of nodes on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I ran your page through profiler, and it actually doesn't look that bad. Javascript execution is within the range of reasonable (245ms). Your problem is reflows (takes around 1073ms) to reflow your page fully within your sliding animations. See screenshot.

[image: DynaTrace log]

There are a few things you can do to improve this. First of all, remove margin from your btnList_Type_Div element, as well as padding. JQuery Animation framework is written quite poorly. When you call slide function, it actually runs 5 different animations at the same time, 2 for margins, 2 for padding and one for width or height of your element. Having margins on your element (even though they are not getting animated in your case) is not great for animation. This should improve your reflows quite significantly (in my test it went down from 1073ms down to 217ms).

Second thing I would suggest, get rid of table around your radio buttons, it's absolutely not required for your layout, a few divs will do the trick just fine. If, for some reason, you have to have a table, at least write it out correctly (declare cols with width on each one, set table-layout: fixed style on it, etc.). Tables are quite expansive to reflow, since they have to recalculate the width/height of every cell every time.

Last thing I can suggest (if everything else fails), nest your div inside another one, and then set position: absolute on it. This will take it out of context, which means that nothing else on the page needs to reflow when you change the settings on your div.

Edit:

Oh and one more thing, even though you set your DTD to XHTML Transitional, and Transitional is more forgiving then Strict, you should still try to follow XHTML format, like closing br and input tags, setting the case correctly on tag names, etc. All of this can affect performance greatly as well.

Edit 2:

Since you didn't post the whole source of the page, including all javascripts and css files, I can't really profile it correctly. More than that, my computer might be more powerful than yours, and might still not be able choppiness in the performance of the animation. I suggest you try to profile the page yourself. For that, you will need to install [DynaTrace Ajax](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/). Run it, start profiling for IE, it will open default version of IE installed on your machine. Navigate to your page, at that point I suggest setting a mark, just so it would be easier to find, then click on your radio button (and perform whatever other actions you want to profile). Close your browser, and in DynaTrace, you should see a new session on the right, expand it and navigate into PurePaths view. Find the mark you set (should be Mark 1 by default) and then look around it for click events and rendering activities. Once you found something that looks like it's taking longer than it should (duration), you can click on it and expand all child actions until you find what is causing an issue. Now by tweaking HTML, you should be able to profile it each time, till you get close to the result you are looking for.

P.S. If you set position:absolute on your div, you have to wrap it into another div, with position:relative on it, as well as height. Setting absolute positioning will take your div out of context, and parent div will have a height of 0px, unless you set it manually yourself.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed I posted a wrong screenshot. That's a screenshot of the profiler after removal of the margins. Before, it would show Rendering activities below highlighted row at 1073ms duration.

Comment: Thanks Ill try this stuff. Looks like asp.net automatically puts that table around the Radio button list? Because its not in my markup but shows up in the actual html.

Comment: That's correct, radio button list will get wrapped into table by ASP.NET, however, if I'm not mistaken (and it's been a really long time) there's a switch on that control to change from table to div. Again, if I'm not mistaken, the property is called RepeatLayout, or something like that.

Comment: I have tried the first two, both using a different RepeatLayout and a simple html radio button list rather than asp version. Also removed all margins, I still see what I would say is choppiness in the animation. For the last one nesting a position:absolute div, when I change to position: absolute the div disappears? Its nested inside a position:relative container, if that matters.

Comment: I also noticed that if the window is taken down to about half screen this animation improves alot, or if I place it by itself in another page it works better, so I think something else on the page is hampering the animation. There is a repeat-x div at the bottom that moves up and down, maybe thats it.

Comment: I added the comment about profiling the page into my answer. You have to understand, that every time your animation ticks, browser has to recalculate position and size of majority of the elements on the page, this includes the element that you are animating, as well, as everything below it. But that's not even the expensive part. If after recalculation, browser decides that in needs to move elements around (like footer in your case), it will have to repaint those elements too, repainting is very expensive. Setting position absolute on the div will ensure that it will not affect things below.